# Login page in Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, singlepage

I'm building a Single Page Application, read that login page should not be on the same page. Should I have login as a separate html page, or can I have login also in the same page.

If I have login as a different page, depending on the first page that I load should have to redirect to the other in client side.

ie suppose I load the SPA first, and if the user is not logged in, I've to redirect to login page in client side. and suppose I load the login page first, and the user is already logged in, I've to redirect to SPA in client side.

What is the general solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I'd put login and verification in a separate page and then use ajax to make the calls.

1. User access index-file.
2. Index-file makes checks with server-side page to see if user is logged in or not.
3. Page displays content depending on if the json answer from the server-side page was true or false.

Then I'd do the same for logging in.

1. User provides login information
2. Checks with server-side file through ajax and json.
3. Page refreshes if succesful or throws error response if it's not.

The bottom line to my answer is that when creating single-page applications, ajax is the way to go. However, since you havent provided what language you're using, i'm unable to give you a more detailed answer.

Client side single page handling logins and content selection however is **very bad practice and should be avoided all-together because of their lack of security** (I cant stress this enough) since all elements will be available even to anonymous access and DOM manipulation will enable an unauthorized user to access restricted content. You'll have to use ajax to do backend serverside authorizations - as mentioned, as well as serverside code on the SPA that present different content depending on your authorization status.

The scenario you describe need to have server-side code for selecting what content to present and client-side code together with ajax for implementing features on the SPA.

What you CAN do however, is to - when for example pushing the login button - calling another file with ajax, remove the content of the wrapper div and append the ajax response to that div. Then you'll avoid client side redirections all together.

Comment: the two pages that i was talking about is login and application, both are HTML page, not verification, it happens in backend.
If login and application are in different HTML page, I've to do a client side redirect, which I didn't like. I wanted a solution to avoid this.

Comment: Did the revision answer your question? If so, please mark the question as answered.